# Finding files on mounted disk with locate

Tags: linux, file-search, locate

I have a small SSD disk with my linux system, and a large IDE disk with most of my work, that is mounted at system start. For some reason I can't seem to find files on the IDE disk using `locate`. I don't know if the error lies in me not giving correct flags to `locate` or if the IDE disk is ignored by `updatedb` (*i.e.* not indexed hence not searchable). How can I accomplish this?

I do find the files if I go to the mount folder and run

```
$ find . -name "my_pattern"
```

but it is quite slow.

Comment: Look at your `/etc/updatedb.conf`. It contains the `PRUNEFS` and `PRUNEPATHS` which might exclude your IDE drive. If it does, change that file so that it doesn't exclude your drive. And then run `updatedb`. If this doesn't work or you don't know what to change in that file, please include the line from `mount` that has your IDE drive, and the contents of `/etc/updatedb.conf`.

Comment: You were absolutely correct! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it, to mark that it has been successfully settled.

Comment: (This is a dummy comment to just notify @DanD, since I forgot to do it in the original comment. I'll delete once you've seen it.)

Answer (score 6):

As @DanD explainedin his comment, `/etc/updatedb.conf` contains settings for what paths and file systems to prune (not index). Indeed I found my mount point among those paths, and upon removing it everything worked fine.